# Retrieve row 1 of column that matches data of a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am working with two tables, and I am trying to pull the data from the first row in a column that has a value in that column that matches the data in A2.

Example tables...

```
ID#s  RESULT
9
17
49
43
5
32
46
56
20
36
37

test1   test2   test3   test4   test5   test6   test7
  1       9       17      25      33      41      49
  2       10      18      26      34      42      50
  3       11      19      27      35      43      51
  4       12      20      28      36      44      52
  5       13      21      29      37      45      53
  6       14      22      30      38      46      54
  7       15      23      31      39      47      55
  8       16      24      32      40      48      56
```

So basically, these are two different tables. Looking at the first table, I want the formula to go into B2 and find the value in A2 (In this case, the number 9) and then find it on the second table and return the value in the first row of the column the 9 is in. So B2 should return "test2" because it found the number 9 in the column for "test2". End result would look like the below...

```
ID#s  RESULT
9      test2
17     test3
49     test7
43     test6
5      test1
32     test4
46     test6
56     test7
20     test3
36     test5
37     test5
```

Any idea how I would go about this? Hopefully I have explained what I am requesting help with thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula entered by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`

```
=OFFSET(Table2,0,MAX(IF(A2=Table2,COLUMN(Table2)))-COLUMN(Table2))
```

Given your data, we return:

[image]

If you should happen to have Excel 2016, and also want to use a Table with structured references, you could, instead, use this formula (also entered with CSE):

```
=TEXTJOIN(,,IF(A2=myDataTable,myDataTable[#Headers],""))
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Edit'd to add some info for those using 2016

Answer (score -2):

this is possible with VLOOKUP method. This page explains very good how you can use it: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this is done with VLOOKUP? It would not be able to find my 9 because it is in the 2nd column, let alone return the first row in the column.

Comment: Sorry missunderstood question: =HLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A2:G8, 1, FALSE)

Comment: That still would not work. You're starting on A2 on the second table, and returning the first result. Your function would return 9 for the value 9 in A2. HLOOKUP begins on the first row of your range and goes down, not up, so if you changed that 1 to a 2, it would return "10" and so on..

Comment: @GreatSUN, it fails when ID# = 2.

Comment: To further elaborate on what pcw said, it would not work on any row A3:G9. It only works on the first row of your range, as I stated. This means in order to get it to return a result when ID# = 2, the range would need to be A3:G9 and so on.